# Assign the entire QueryString to a String?

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-8, query-string, tostring

I've passed a really long Query String from one page to another in my Windows Phone 8 project.

I need to pass these parameters from the new page to another page but don't want to reconstruct he entire QueryString.

Is there a way to assign the entire QueryString to a new String?

Something like

```
String newQuery = NavigationContext.QueryString.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to pass these parameters from the new page to another page but
>   don't want to reconstruct the entire QueryString

Why not? This is programming: do all the work in one place so you don't have to do it again later. Let's use an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to do this.

## Silverlight

Place this code in a static class...

```
public string ToQueryString(this IDictionary dict)
    {
    string querystring = "";
    foreach(string key in dict.AllKeys)
        {
        querystring += key + "=" + dict[key] + "&";
        }
    return querystring;
    }
```

Use it like this...

```
string QueryString = NavigationContext.QueryString.ToQueryString();
```

## ASP.NET

When I originally read this question, I thought it was for ASP.NET, not Silverlight. I'll leave the ASP.NET answer here in case someone stumbles across it looking for how to do it in ASP.NET.

```
public string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection qs)
{
    string querystring = "";
    foreach(string key in qs.AllKeys)
        {
        querystring += key + "=" + qs[key] + "&";
        }
    return querystring;
}
```

Use it like this...

```
string QueryString = Request.QueryString.ToQueryString();
```

---

There is something that already exists for ASP.NET. But I feel it's important to demonstrate that you can do all the work once somewhere. Then not have to do it again. If you want to use a built-in way, something like this would work, using the [Query property of the Uri class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string QueryString = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query;
```

Comment: The type in this case is IDictionary<String,String> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: @Nick Missed that. I have added Silverlight example.

Comment: @mason I'm using c#, The "built in way" doesn't work for me as HtmlPage doesn't appear to exist, unless I have to include something? 

I wasn't against programming something, I'm just used to web development when grabbing a URL Query String is normally a built in command.

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer I updated the answer to fully qualify the path to HtmlPage. Try now. You could also add a using statement to the top of your class, ex: `using System.Windows.Browser;` People often leave the namespace off their SO answers. If you're using Visual Studio, Intellisense can detect the namespace for you if you hover over HtmlPage, and then click one of the options that appears to  either fully qualify it or add the using statement.

Comment: @mason the full path doesn't help as the .Browser namespace doesn't exist within system.windows. I'm familiar with the hover feature of VisualStudio, but in this case there is no option to do so. I already includes the "system.windows" namespace. Any further ideas?

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer Try adding a reference to System.Windows.Browser assembly (right click your Reference folder, then click Add Reference). I'm not sure if it's available in Windows Phone 8. Let me know, I'll delete my answer if it's not available.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid @mason

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer Okay, well try the extension method way and see if that works for your purposes.

Comment: I get the error: 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>' does not contain a definition for 'ToQueryString' and no extension method 'ToQueryString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer Did you make sure that you placed the extension method in a static class, ex: `public static class MyExtensionMethods` and make sure that it's in the same namespace as the class you're calling from (or that you've imported the namespace)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that may be a little simpler...

You could project the results into a format of your choosing. Here's a simple example below.
I've used an `IDictionary<string,string>` as it is the [underlying type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for `NavigationContext.QueryString`

```
var test = new Dictionary<String,String>();
test.Add("1", "one");
test.Add("2", "two");
test.Add("3", "three");

// Choose any string format you wish and project to array
var newArray = test.Select(item => item.Key + ":" + item.Value).ToArray();

// Join on any separator
string output = String.Join(",", newArray);
```

This still means that you have to interpret the result later (according to the format you chose). Here you'll get a format like

```
"1:one,2:two,3:three"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've sent it as a querystring just pull it back out on the OnNavigatedTo() Method and then you can store the query in the page until you move on?.

```
string newQuery;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    newQuery = NavigationContext.QueryString["queryName"];
}
```

Comment: so this will story the ENTIRE Query string? I have numerous parameters in the string.

Comment: Ah my apologises, I didnt realises you had numerous parameters. In which case, I'd suggest something like what @mason has suggested. If you put it in a static class you can call it from anywhere, and again store it in the page until you decide to move on and use it as your Uri string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public string GetQueryString()
{
    IDictionary<String, String> NavigationContextData = NavigationContext.QueryString;
    string data = "/Pagename.xaml?";
    foreach (var item in NavigationContextData)
    {
        data += item.Key + "=" + item.Value + "&";
    }
    data = data.Substring(0, data.Length - 1);
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in your `OnNavigatedTo()` event, you can use a quick, easy two-liner. This can be condensed to a single line or expanded to check for the existence of the `?` character. If you know that there are always parameters passed, the check is unnecessary and these two lines work fine:

```
string QStr = e.Uri.ToString();
string ParmStr = QStr.Substring(QStr.IndexOf('?') + 1);
```

You can also condense it into a single line:

```
string ParmStr = e.Uri.ToString().Substring(e.Uri.ToString().IndexOf('?') + 1);
```